# how to run sql query in sequence using python and where condition input to be given during the run time

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I want to run few sql queries in sequence. Output of the sql query to be written to a file. input of the where condition to be passed during run time like python 1.py 201

```
import pyodbc
import csv

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select emp_name from emp where id=<run_time>")

with open("output.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in cursor:
        writer.writerow(row)

cursor.execute("select emp_name from emp where date=<run_time>")
with open("output1.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in cursor:
        writer.writerow(row)

cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

check if it will work.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you asking somebody else to check if your code will work? That should be pretty trivial, and after that you could ask why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Please pick between mysql and sql-server in your question tags.

Comment: @ChristianW. Let me check and get back

Comment: @MisterPositive Thank you. Just did.